# Windows Task Scheduler shows Last Run Time = Never, even though task has run every day this week

Tags: windows-server-2012-r2, task-scheduler

I have a VBScript file that is run by the Task Scheduler, every day.  The task was manually created on 6th February 2017, using the regular *Create Task* GUI, and has a Weekly trigger with Monday-Friday checked and a start time of 08:00.

It runs the VBScript file, using a *Start a program* action of:

- Program/script: `%SystemRoot%\system32\cscript.exe`
- Add Arguments:  `x:\pathto\scriptname.vbs //NOLOGO //E:VBS //B`
- Start In:       `x:\pathto`

I have history records that prove that the task has run, and it is not being updated or replaced by Group Policy Preferences.

The same script runs on all my servers — same script, same trigger, same action — and has just started happening on four different Windows Server 2012 R2 servers at once, but has not occurred on any of my Windows Server 2008 R2 instances.

When I recreated the task on one of the affected servers, it started reporting Last Run Time again.  Is this some known issue?  Any known fixes?  My Google-fu is letting me down.

[image: Screenshot of Task Scheduler]